# Tag bug: Replication

Tags: bug

When I tried to add the listed tag “replication” to a [question I had edited on viral RNA-dependent RNA replicase](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/100885/why-are-there-two-replicase-proteins-translated-from-tobacco-mosaic-virus-rna) I discovered it had become “DNA-replication”! Attempts to edit it again failed.

Why? and Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer: replication as a tag is a synonym for dna-replication. Entering a synonym makes the system to replace it by the main tag.
In the past it has only been used synonymous, so at one point the synonym was created. Look [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) for tag synonyms.

Comment: Simple, but perhaps also simplistic. In an era when there are fifteen different tags for the dreaded lurgy (or so it seemed) there doesn’t seem to be one that relates to the replication of its genome. Simple fix?

Comment: @David Tag maintenance is pretty ad-hoc rather than systematic; pretty much when someone notices a problem they either handle it or raise the issue and it gets fixed. Given what a pain retagging is and how users use tags inconsistently, there is both a lot of mess in how they are used.

Comment: @BryanKrause — I realize that. And by the time one has dealt with the problem it has passed. I suppose I should fix it myself, but one has to decide where best to spend one's time.

Comment: @David Would a new tag "RNA replication" make sense? or "viral replication"? I think the latter is sometimes used for the whole process including protein synthesis and viral assembly but I'm not in that field and am not certain.

Comment: Alternatively maybe a new tag "genome replication" and make that the synonym target? I forget what the limits are on what can be a synonym for what, though... Just "replication" seems too vague as the target since it could be mistakenly used for, say, "cell division" more broadly.

Comment: @BryanKrause. Let me think about it. I’m watching football at the moment.

Comment: @BryanKrause — I think your suggestion of "viral replication" is good. No need to distinguish between different types of viruses.

Comment: @BryanKrause speaking of "...or rase the issue and it gets fixed": [How to tag questions about animals surviving being frozen for a long time? Is a new tag needed or should we adjust the cryonics usage guidance?](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4208/27918)