# How to tag questions about animals or other living things surviving being frozen for a long time? Is a new tag needed or just adjust cryonics tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tagging, tag-management, retagging

[Has the 2018 report of nematodes frozen for 30 to 40,000 years been confirmed? Has 14C dating confirmed their age?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/101112/27918) asks about a July 2018 paper in Doklady Biological Sciences [*Viable Nematodes from Late Pleistocene Permafrost of the Kolyma River Lowland*](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1134/S0012496618030079).

Typing things like *stasis, frozen, freezing, surviva..., thaw..., preser...* all return zero tag suggestions.

There is no [psychrophile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychrophile) tag but of course that wouldn't apply.

There is the [cryonics](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryonics) tag (<s>7</s> 8 questions) and the community's usage of that tag suggests it would apply here despite its usage guidance:

> the low-temperature preservation (usually at −196°C) of people who cannot be sustained by contemporary medicine, with the hope that resuscitation and restoration to full health may be possible in the far future.

To me it seems that [cryonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryonics) is not the right tag for the natural survival of animals or any organism undergoing freezing, so I think we need a new tag and a bit of re-tagging of those other questions.

**Question:** What do others think? How should we tag questions about the natural ability of animals or other living things surviving being frozen for a long time? Is a new tag needed or should we adjust the cryonics usage guidance?

Also, should there be a separate tag for the *laboratory technique* of freezing living cells, tissues or complete organisms for storage, or can these all be put under one tag?

Comment: With just a quick look and without much thought, I agree cryonics doesn't make sense here. Not sure if there needs to be another tag, though; tags are mainly to help people who have a particular interest follow questions that are relevant to them. If you want to retag a bunch of old questions with a new tag it's probably best to start with that as a proposal: "here's the tag I'd apply", "here are some questions that could use this tag", etc. There are infinite potentially useful tags but unless there is some collection of questions that could use them, it's kind of moot.

Comment: @BryanKrause I've mentioned that there are 8 question tagged with cryonics and if there is some agreement that a different tag for the natural ability of living things to survive freezing then roughly five of the eight would probably be candidates for retagging. I can list the eight questions (grouped as keep cryonics and retag candidates) would that help?

Comment: @BryanKrause I have some [experience with this](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/703) maybe I can search this site deeper to look for thinks like freezing + storage (15 questions) and freezing + survival (5 questions) to see what the total scope of the situation is.